# Safe navigation operator (&.) in Python

Tags: python

So, I've been using Ruby for some time, and I'm wondering if there is something like the [safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator) `&.` in Python.

[Here](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) is an example of when to use the safe operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not have a safe navigation operator. It was proposed in [PEP 505](https://peps.python.org/pep-0505/), however has been deferred.

Comment: [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator#Python)

Comment: Thanks. I hope it happens soon.

Comment: @Anthony Sorry to disappoint -- but it's not on a track to implementation. Don't hold your breath.

Comment: That's shame for Python =/